# interactive で文字列をクエリする際に、既定の候補から選択するには？

Tags: elisp

interactive な関数を定義する際に、その引数を、複数ある候補から指定したいと思っています。

```
; 次のような候補リストがあるとする
(setq candidates '("foo" "bar" "piyo"))

; the-candidate を candidates の中からひとつ選びたい
(defun some-func (the-candidate)
  (interactive (list ???))
)
```

これは一般的にどのように実現されますか？

Comment: [Adding Completion to (interactive)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382524/adding-completion-to-interactive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@metropolis さんに紹介された、 https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382677/3090068 がドンピシャでした。

今回のケースに当てはめると、次のように実現できました。

```
(setq candidates '("foo" "bar" "piyo"))

(defun some-func (the-candidate)
  (interactive
   (list
    (completing-read "Choose one: " candidates)))
  (prin1 the-candidate))
```